# Global variable not showing up in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I'm using webpack, my global variable is not working. Any idea why?

```
var s = {
  name : 'Goku',
  fn : function(){
    return this.fn2.bind(window)();
  },
  fn2 : function(){
    return this.x;
  }

};

var x = 45;
console.log(s.name);
console.log(s.fn());  should say 45 since it's rebinded. getting undefined
```

Comment: this seems like a bad idea...

Comment: webpack treats every file as a module. Hence `var x = 45;` will create a module local variable, not a global variable. If you want to create a global variable you can do `window.x = 45;` or `global.x = 45;`. But there is no reason to use a global variable.

Comment: If you're that advanced that you're using webpack, you don't need globals. Just design better modules. The only good global is a namespace global to access 3rd party stuff you can't import in any other way.

Comment: ok.. i thought webpack was jsut a bundler. didn't realize it did all that... i am learing more about amds and commonjs